# PHP: return only one time function in for loop

Tags: php, wordpress, email, for-loop, upload

I have a `for` loop and inside it I am uploading multiple images. Once an image is uploaded, I send an email notification to admin via `wp_mail()`.

Things are working fine and sending email notification as well. However the issue is that notification email sending as per image count. Means if upload 1 image than one notification email if 4 than 4 notification email (as it's in the loop). However I want notification send only once no matter either one or 10 images.

Here is my entire code:

```
global $wpdb, $post;
$upload_path = wp_upload_dir();            
$post_id = $post->ID;

$upload_dir = $upload_path['basedir'].'/review-media/'.$post_id.'/'.get_current_user_id().'/';
$thumbnail_dir = $upload_dir.'thumbnail/';
$upload_url = $upload_path['baseurl'].'/review-media/'.$post_id.'/'.get_current_user_id().'/thumbnail/';


self::create_path($thumbnail_dir);


if (isset($_FILES['photo']) === true) {

    $errors = array();            
    $allowed_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

    $files = $_FILES['photo'];

    for($x = 0; $x < count($files['name']); $x++) {

        $file_name = $files['name'][$x]; 
        $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
        $file_size = $files['size'][$x];
        $file_tmp = $files['tmp_name'][$x];

        if($file_tmp)
        list($img_width, $img_height) = getimagesize($file_tmp);

        $min_img_width = 1;
        $min_img_height = 1;
        $max_img_width = 2000;
        $max_img_height = 2000;


        if (!$file_tmp) {
            $errors[] = '<p>Please select the file</p>';    
        }

        if (($file_tmp) && (($img_width > $max_img_width) || ($img_width < $min_img_width)) && (($img_height > $max_img_height) || ($img_height < $min_img_height))) {
            $errors[] = '<p>Size of <strong>'.$file_name.'</strong> must be within '. $min_img_width .'px to '. $max_img_width .'px</p>';
        }

        if ( ($file_tmp) && (in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext) === false) ) {                
            $errors[] = '<p>Extension <strong>'.$file_ext.'</strong> not allowed</p>';
            unlink($file_tmp);                                
        }

        if ($file_size > 2097152) {                
            $errors[] = '<p>File <strong>'.$file_name.'</strong> size must be under 2mb</p>';
            unlink($file_tmp);                
        }

        if(empty($errors)) {   

            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $upload_dir.$file_name);

            //crop and resize to images and thumbnails
            $target_file = $upload_dir.$file_name; // original file
            $resized_file = $upload_dir.$file_name; // max resized file
            $med_file = $upload_dir.'medium-'.$file_name; // medium resized fiel
            $thumbnail = $thumbnail_dir.$file_name; // thumbnail file
            $large_width = 1024; // upload resize max width
            $large_height = 1024; // upload resize max height
            $thumb_width = 150; // thumbnail width
            $thumb_height = 150; // thumbnail height
            $med_width = $thumb_width * 1.5; // medium resized image width
            $med_height = $thumb_height * 1.5; // medium resized image height

            // resize to maximum width and height
            self::resize_image($target_file, $resized_file, $large_width, $large_height, $file_ext);
            // resize with 1.5 multi of thumb width and height to generate thumbnail
            self::resize_image($target_file, $med_file, $med_width, $med_height, $file_ext);     
            // crop image uisng medium resized image               
            self::crop_thumbnai(file_exists($med_file) ? $med_file : $target_file, $thumbnail, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $file_ext);

            // delete medium resized file after thumbnail creation.
            if (file_exists($med_file))
                unlink($med_file);

            self::insert_image($file_name);

            //self::get_uploaded_image();
            echo '<div class="upload-status-thumb">';
            echo '<img src="'.$upload_url.$file_name.'" alt="imge" />';
            echo '</div>';

            // send notification email to admin on image upload
            self::email_notification($post_id);                   

        } else {                
            foreach ($errors as $error) {                    
                echo $error;                    
            }                
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Send the notification *once after the loop*, not during each loop iteration.

Comment: but than how can I check form has been submitted or not? However I have tried to place after loop but it is still sending number of time image uploaded. You can give more negative votes if you can never mind :) as far as I learn something new :)

Comment: More specifically, since you're emailing if there are no errors record `$success=true` where your script currently sends an email and, outside of the loop, ask `if ($success)` and if so, then send the email.

Comment: @popnoodles can you please help me to understand where to add $success and what the variable will holds?

Comment: See Rid Iculous or HeXa's answers. NB HeXa has used a new line after the condition which can confuse new programmers. Only the one line gets executed after that condition.

Comment: @popnoodles  Oh yeh I am getting it. Thanks a lot for your help..

Comment: Additional tip: if your operation completes successfully, don't render HTML - redirect to self. This is useful to prevent problems resubmitting the form if/when users use the 'back' button in their browsers. You can add info about success/failure to the session, and read it back after the redirect.

Comment: @halfer Oh yeh this is nice idea. But than again need some hint how to do that? Can I do it using header location?

Comment: Yes, so you can do `header( 'Location: /your/upload/form.php?success=' . ($isSuccess ? 1 : 0) ); exit();`. Then in your page, detect the `success` query string and report that the upload succeeded, perhaps using `$_SESSION` (or the WP wrapper for it) to store per-upload data you wish to report (e.g. filenames).

Comment: Alright! got it.. thanks a lot for your help.. appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your email content in one variable ($msg below) and amend the information every iteration of the loop. When the loop has finished, check if the variable has been modified, if so email its content.

This should work:

```
    global $wpdb, $post;
    $upload_path = wp_upload_dir();            
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $msg = false;

    $upload_dir = $upload_path['basedir'].'/review-media/'.$post_id.'/'.get_current_user_id().'/';
    $thumbnail_dir = $upload_dir.'thumbnail/';
    $upload_url = $upload_path['baseurl'].'/review-media/'.$post_id.'/'.get_current_user_id().'/thumbnail/';


    self::create_path($thumbnail_dir);


    if (isset($_FILES['photo']) === true) {

        $errors = array();            
        $allowed_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

        $files = $_FILES['photo'];

        for($x = 0; $x < count($files['name']); $x++) {

            $file_name = $files['name'][$x]; 
            $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
            $file_size = $files['size'][$x];
            $file_tmp = $files['tmp_name'][$x];

            if($file_tmp)
            list($img_width, $img_height) = getimagesize($file_tmp);

            $min_img_width = 1;
            $min_img_height = 1;
            $max_img_width = 2000;
            $max_img_height = 2000;


            if (!$file_tmp) {
                $errors[] = '<p>Please select the file</p>';    
            }

            if (($file_tmp) && (($img_width > $max_img_width) || ($img_width < $min_img_width)) && (($img_height > $max_img_height) || ($img_height < $min_img_height))) {
                $errors[] = '<p>Size of <strong>'.$file_name.'</strong> must be within '. $min_img_width .'px to '. $max_img_width .'px</p>';
            }

            if ( ($file_tmp) && (in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext) === false) ) {                
                $errors[] = '<p>Extension <strong>'.$file_ext.'</strong> not allowed</p>';
                unlink($file_tmp);                                
            }

            if ($file_size > 2097152) {                
                $errors[] = '<p>File <strong>'.$file_name.'</strong> size must be under 2mb</p>';
                unlink($file_tmp);                
            }

            if(empty($errors)) {   

                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $upload_dir.$file_name);

                //crop and resize to images and thumbnails
                $target_file = $upload_dir.$file_name; // original file
                $resized_file = $upload_dir.$file_name; // max resized file
                $med_file = $upload_dir.'medium-'.$file_name; // medium resized fiel
                $thumbnail = $thumbnail_dir.$file_name; // thumbnail file
                $large_width = 1024; // upload resize max width
                $large_height = 1024; // upload resize max height
                $thumb_width = 150; // thumbnail width
                $thumb_height = 150; // thumbnail height
                $med_width = $thumb_width * 1.5; // medium resized image width
                $med_height = $thumb_height * 1.5; // medium resized image height

                // resize to maximum width and height
                self::resize_image($target_file, $resized_file, $large_width, $large_height, $file_ext);
                // resize with 1.5 multi of thumb width and height to generate thumbnail
                self::resize_image($target_file, $med_file, $med_width, $med_height, $file_ext);     
                // crop image uisng medium resized image               
                self::crop_thumbnai(file_exists($med_file) ? $med_file : $target_file, $thumbnail, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $file_ext);

                // delete medium resized file after thumbnail creation.
                if (file_exists($med_file))
                    unlink($med_file);

                self::insert_image($file_name);

                //self::get_uploaded_image();
                echo '<div class="upload-status-thumb">';
                echo '<img src="'.$upload_url.$file_name.'" alt="imge" />';
                echo '</div>';

                // add to message var
               $msg .= 'image added: '.$post_id."\n";                   

            } else {                
                foreach ($errors as $error) {                    
                    echo $error;                    
                }                
            }

        }

     if($msg){ // if msg is no longer false email it to admin
        self::email_notification($msg);
     }

    }
```

Comment: `$msg = false;` and `$msg.='...'` does PHP convert a bool to a string with no warnings?

Comment: No the function sending email notification perfectly no issue but only the things as it is in for loop it is sending number of time the image uploads. Means if user select 3 images to upload than email also sending 3 times

Comment: can't speak for all but 5.3 does, yup

Comment: @pixelngrain this will only send one email, but I would use `$msg='';` instead of `$msg = false;` and `if (!empty($msg))` instead of `if ($msg)` to avoid mixing types.

Comment: @popnoodles - yeah, yours is better, but I always liked PHP exactly for its ability to deal with diff types so easily. if they ever change that I am screwed :/

Comment: I find it's best to be precise but at least you declared it. The amount of times I get undefined variable errors from other programmers' code is ridiculous.

Comment: @RidIculous yours and `HeXa` both answers are almost the same and no confuse which answered I should select. :P but selecting yours as you have give some explanation. Thanks a lot for your great help

Comment: @popnoodles: Oh, I do code with E_ALL. Not declaring and mixing type are 2 diff things...

Answer (score 1):

easy work :

```
$message = "" ;
for($x = 0; $x < count($files['name']); $x++) {
    if(empty($errors)) {  
       move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $upload_dir.$file_name);
       $message .= "$file_name successfuly uploaded in ". Date("H:i:s") ." ".$post->ID." \n\r" ;
       # something else  ... 
    }
    # something else  ... 
}
if($message!='')
   self::email_notification($message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect post ID's to be notified into an array, and then after the for loop call email_notification passing the array of ID's to it. Modify the email_notification function to accept an array of IDs instead of one ID, and include all IDs in the email (iterate through the ID array with a foreach loop for example).

Comment: I am sorry for confusion but this is only for one post. The image upload form is on single post

Answer (score -1):

Use a boolean variable inside the loop. Set it to true initially, and && it with the success of the individual image uploads.

Then, after the loop finishes executing, you can check that variable and send your email notification.

ie.

```
if ({success}) {
  $boolVar = $boolVar && true;
} else {
  $boolVar = $boolVar && false;
}
```

If you still want the ids in the email, you'll need to collect them during the loop.

Comment: Oh never used this. need help to understand where to place and how to use